# Ramda indices in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, currying, ramda.js

Trying to get to grips with Ramda and loving it so far, however I'm struggling with something that seems quite basic (sorry if this is a duplicate)

I've got an array of arrays (representing a game board)

```
const board = [
  [4, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2],
  [4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3],
  [4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4],
  [0, 2, 4, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2],
  [4, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1],
  [3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 0, 1, 3],
  [2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2],
  [3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3]
]
```

The player builds up a move with matching tiles, so something like:

```
const move = [[7, 4], [7, 5], [6, 5]]
```

I'd like to map the tiles where the move coordiantes match to a different value (e.g. the `1`s at those coordiantes would become `-1`)

I'm aware Ramda can augment R.map with R.addIndex: `const mapWithIndex = R.map(R.addIndex)` so `mapWithIndex((i, value) => // do something))` would get access to the index of each tile but I'm sure how to pass down all the arguments to the lowest level

I can't even add i and j together, have tried something like:

```
const mapWithIndex = R.addIndex(R.map)
const addIndices = mapWithIndex((i, row) => mapWithIndex((j, tile) => j + i))
```

But calling this function returns an array of functions.

What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues:

- the inner `mapWithIndex` needs access to `row` so it can iterate through the tiles
- the value and index parameters were reversed in your sample code

This should do it:

```
const mapWithIndex = R.addIndex(R.map);
const addIndices = mapWithIndex((row, i) => mapWithIndex((tile, j) => j + i)(row));
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much, don't know why I thought the index argument came first. I guess my next question is how could I break this down into smaller units that can pass the player moves array as an argument as well as the i, j?